# "The wait operation timed out" during SMO SqlBackup - How do I prevent this?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-10, backup

I have a C# WPF application that needs to back up a local database every so often. I do so using the following code:

```
//Initialise the backup
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup backUp = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup();
backUp.BackupSetName = "File location";
backUp.Devices.AddDevice("File location", DeviceType.File);
backUp.Database = "Database name";
backUp.Incremental = false;
backUp.Initialize = true;
backUp.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
backUp.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(OnBackupUpdate);

//Back up the database
backUp.SqlBackup(Server);
```

I have been using the application on Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8 for many years and never had an issue with it. However, I recently started using it on Windows 10 and on occasion (about 5% of the time, but that's a pure estimate) the backup begins and after 10 minutes the following error is recorded in my application's error logs.

```
28/01/2020 12:46:32  BackupDatabase -> Calling BackupDatabaseSMO
28/01/2020 12:56:32  The wait operation timed out
28/01/2020 12:56:32  Win32 Error: 258 --> 
28/01/2020 12:56:32  Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
28/01/2020 12:56:32  SQL error number = -2 --> SQL server = (local)\MyServer --> SQL state = 0 --> Error code = -2146232060 --> SQL Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. --> 
28/01/2020 12:56:32  An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
28/01/2020 12:56:32  Unknown exception
28/01/2020 12:56:32  Backup failed for Server 'MyPC\MyAccount'. 
28/01/2020 12:56:32  Unknown exception
28/01/2020 12:56:32  Failed to backup the database 'LocalWpfDb' on server 'MyPC\MyAccount'. The following message was returned: The wait operation timed out
```

This has only started happening now I have moved to Windows 10, and it only happens on occasion. Does anyone know of any likely explanations for this, and whether there is a setting I can change on the PC or in the application to stop this from happening?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This is not about the <sql> language.)

Comment: @jarlh I originally used SQL Server 2008 R2, but when I moved to Windows 10 I switched to SQL Server 2016 Express.

Comment: Converting the error number -2146232060 to hex lead me to following : https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/System-Data-SqlClient-SqlException-0x80131904

Comment: Also read this : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d55b675f-c747-4738-aaa9-4768d2180b4c/kms-unknown-error-0x80131904?forum=winservergen

Comment: I've done a lot of research on the web and it looks like this error may just be a timeout where the default timeout in the database is 20 seconds.  Did the size of the database grow?  Did the hard drive type or speed change?   What about the number of cores in the Micro?  When putting a Large SQL server on a machine it is recommended using the faster machine, with the most number of cores, and stuffing it with the maximum amount of memory.  then backups you would expect to take a long time.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry for the late reply. Been distracted by some other stuff but have now come back to this issue. The default timeout isn't 20 seconds. The backup operation times out after 10 minutes. Ordinarily, the backup doesn't even take 10 seconds to complete, so why it would get stuck for 10 minutes and eventually time out completely is confusing. I don't understand why this would only happen sometimes and not EVERY time.

Comment: Where is the mdf located?If I remember correctly you have to archive the file from a local driver.It cannot be on a network folder.The folder must be a local drive on the machine where SQL Server is installed. You can use either a Network file name \\myserver\data\abc.mdf or a drive letter like d:\data\abc.mdf.So if it is on a Network driver you have to De-Attach the file from the server.Copy the file to a local drive.Then re-attach to the server and archive.  I usually just deattach the file and make a copy in windows rather the doing a backup.Backup allows you to archive pieces of the mdf.